# A \(re)newcommand that does not care if a command is already defined

Tags: macros, symbols

Does there exists a version of `\newcommand`, something like `\extranewcommand{\foo}{bar}` which does defines `\foo` to stand for `bar` regardless of whether `\foo` has been previously defined? Of course, if `\foo` is undefined, one can use `\newcommand{\foo}{bar}`, and if it is defined, one can use `\renewcommand{\foo}{bar}`. However, in either case, one has to know which version to use: if one chooses wrong, the document won't compile. What I am interested in is if there exists a similar command (or perhaps a combination of commands, etc.) which will work in either situation.

As a rationalisation for the question, below are two situations in which I would find this command useful. Of course, the change is very minor, but it adds up over time, I think.

1. One doesn't always know what commands are already defined. Sometimes, it happens that a newly defined command happens to also be something defined in some standard package. For instance, one wants to use `\operatorname{Im}` for the image of a linear operator, so it is convenient to declare `\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}`. However, `\Im` is already a fancy symbol for the imaginary part, so a `renewcommand` is needed instead. I never use the mentioned imaginary part symbol, so it would be nice if I could just forget that it exists (but I can't). (Of course, this issue can be solved by compiling, noticing the error and adding "re" in front of "newcommand"; but, there are a lot of other such clashes that happen.)
2. I use a lot of commands used only "locally" (I'm not sure if it's a good coding practice, but I find it useful). For example, if I have a set S which occurs in many places in the text, I would often declare `\newcommand{\Set}{S}` or even `\newcommand{\S}{S}`, so that I can easily change the symbol S to another one if I feel like it. This potentially leads to renewing commands quite frequently, which is not that much of a problem. However, if a block of text with a `\newcommand` moves, then also a prefix `re` has to move. (Again, it is not much of a problem, but I find it a nuisance).

Comment: please be *very* careful!  an author redefined `\i` to be a math function, failing to notice that one of the items in the bibliography was by a russian author whose transliterated name required `\i` (for use with a breve).  it took a ridiculously long time for the production team to figure out (1) why there was a message that math mode was required, and (2) change all the other instances of `\i` to something else (and hoping that no mistakes were made in the process).

Comment: One way to mitigate the risk that @barbarabeeton mentioned is to localize your defined commands by using brackets. For example `{\renewcommand\sum{s_{um}}      $\sum$} $\sum$` would have the same result as typing `$s_{um}$ $\sum$` because the renewed command only remains defined within the brackets.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is `\providecommand` that defines a macro if it is not yet defined. Together with `\renewcommand` you have your "`\extranewcommand`":

```
\providecommand{\foo}{}
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{bar: #1}
```

Or you can switch to the plain TeX primitives (other syntax!), e.g.:

```
\long\def\foo#1{bar: #1}
```

(`\renewcommand` and friends without star use `\long\def` and if the star form is given, `\def` without `\long` is used. Also the parameters are specified differently.)

### `\declarecommand`

A definition of the "requested" `\declarecommand` that calls `\providecommand` and `\renewcommand` together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\declarecommand}{%
  \@star@or@long\declare@command
}
\newcommand*{\declare@command}[1]{%
  \provide@command{#1}{}%
  % \let#1\@empty % would be more efficient, but without error checking
  \renew@command{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\declarecommand*{\foo}{\typeout{foo 1: \meaning\foo}}
\foo
\declarecommand{\foo}{\typeout{foo 2: \meaning\foo}}
\foo
\declarecommand*{\foo}[1]{\typeout{foo #1: \meaning\foo}}
\foo{3}

\end{document}
```

Result:

```
foo 1: macro:->\typeout {foo 1: \meaning \foo }
foo 2: \long macro:->\typeout {foo 2: \meaning \foo }
foo 3: macro:#1->\typeout {foo #1: \meaning \foo }
```

Comment: To be equal to `renewcommand` & friends, it should be `\long\def\foo#1`

Comment: And one could define `\newcommand\declarecommand[1]{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: The star forms of `\renewcommand` and friends use `\def` without `\long`.

Comment: @egreg: Done, a bit more elaborate because of the star forms.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I had already upvoted your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's not as crafty as [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128799/62340) but another option would be

```
\ifdefined\foo
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{bar: #1}
\else
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{bar: #1}
\fi
```

Note that `\ifdefined` is part of the [e-TeX extension](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex?lang=en) and as such part of any modern LaTeX compiler. No packages required.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{to be renewed}
```

in your preamble and then

```
\renewcommmand{\foo}[1]{whatever #1}
```

wherever you like.

If `\foo` happens to be defined when you start out, you'll find that out and can choose another name, or renew in your preamble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but people find it when they Google so I'll put in my solution:

(Make sure to have `\usepackage{suffix}` in the preamble)

```
\long\def \forcecommand #1{\providecommand{#1}{}\renewcommand{#1}}

\WithSuffix\def \forcecommand*#1{\providecommand*{#1}{}\renewcommand*{#1}}
```

`\forcecommand` essentially only "grabs" the first parameter passed to it, applies it to `\providecommand` and `\renewcommand`, then leaves the rest for `\renewcommand`.