# \mathplus fails to render

Tags: errors, texlive, r, markdown

I'm new to LaTeX - can anyone suggest why the `$\mathplus$` is not rendering as `+`?

It can be seen in the [bibliography entry of another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209783/how-do-i-remove-interior-brackets-from-a-range-of-superscript-citations),

```
publisher = {Springer Science $\mathplus$ Business Media},
```

Identically to how I'm trying to use it, in [Rmarkdown](https://github.com/cboettig/knitcitations/issues/69) (which basically runs R code then writes markdown). I have `texlive-full` installed on Linux Mint, and am writing using the *xelatex* engine, via `knitr` (which writes to PDF using pandoc).

Can anyone suggest what else I need to use this character? Is there a list somewhere of which 'control sequences' are found in which packages etc.?

Comment: I have never seen that command (but it might exist). In any case, why not write `+` directly?

Comment: @Manuel it's not me writing it: the [`knitcitations`](https://github.com/cboettig/knitcitations/issues/69) package is providing the reference *indirectly*, dynamically (from a [DOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier)) is the problem, so I can't get rid of it.

Comment: @lmmx just stick `\newcommand\mathplus{+}` in your document and it will be defined.

Comment: Just for reference: see this (closed) [issue](https://github.com/cboettig/knitcitations/issues/69) on the `knitcitations` repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can not remove this (rather pointless) definition as it is being auto-generated, put

```
\newcommand\mathplus{+}
```

in your document preamble so that `\mathplus` expands to `+`.

Comment: Would it be better to use `\providecommand\mathplus{+}` to avoid confusions if [amsfont's amssymb](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts) is loaded later in the writing process? For others: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128799/9075 for difference of `\providecommand` and `\newcommand`.

Comment: @koppor ??? `amssymb` doesn't define `\mathplus` ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `unicode-math` package by adding:

```
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
```

in the beginning of your file.

remember to delete all auxiliary files including the `.bbl` file then run your `.tex` file using `XeLaTeX` and again using `BibTeX` and again using `XeLaTeX`.